# Framework colorama работает только в консоли в idle выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
init()
print(Back.RED + "Фон этого текста красный!!!" )
```

Пытаюсь запустить выдаёт ошибку:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:/coloramma2.py", line 1,
> in <module>
>     from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style ImportError: cannot 
> import name 'init' from 'colorama' (E:\colorama.py)
> ```

Comment: в документации указано, что init имел смыл использовать, если у вас 32-битная система, скорее всего в вашем случае решением, будет являться удаление init. В описании фрэиворка сказано, что это "кросплатформенный цветной текст для консоли - Python", так с чего ему работать в idle? Полагаю, вы можете редактировать код где угодно, а запускать только из консоли

Comment: На маке работает(в терминале).В idle это не будет работать по любому.

Comment: К тому же colorama - это библиотека.

Comment: Судя по приведенному тексту, вы импортируете не из установленного модуля colorama, а из файла colorama.py, лежащего рядом с вашим модулем coloramma2.py на диске E. Нужно убрать этот модуль, и ошибка уйдет. Но в любом случае консоль IDLE не поддерживает цветной текст.